# SKAction move forward

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

How do I get a `SKNode` to move forward?

I've been able to get the node to move in a fixed direction using `[SKAction moveByX:y:duration:]` but I want it to move in a direction relative to the direction its facing.

I am looking to make each node turn 45 degrees then "walk" forward 50 pixels.

It seems simple enough I just am not able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

This will rotate, then towards where you tap

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(location.x - _myPlayer.position.x, location.y - _myPlayer.position.y);

        CGFloat angleRadians = atan2f(diff.y, diff.x);

        [_myPlayer runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                [SKAction rotateToAngle:angleRadians duration:1.0],
                                [SKAction moveByX:diff.x y:diff.y duration:3.0]
                                ]]];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about this as well. I want to make a node that can seem to be turning before proceeding. One way I have considered doing this is to have a child node attached the the "forward-most" portion of the node that is moving in the scene. Then I would calculate the distance of the tap form the child node. Does that make sense?  Essentially, I would be able to calculate the front of the node from a tap anywhere in the scene.