# How to do impulse physics

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, physics

Okay guys, I have two sprites one the enemy who moves to pick up items around the map as the items appear and it does that using SKActions then also I have the wall which he shouldn't go through. anyway. all I am trying to do is to make him bounce out if he hits the wall. How would I go about that?

Here is the code below:

// for the Enemy wall I have this code:

```
- (void) EnemyBelongings {
EnemyWall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"EnemyWall@2x"];
EnemyWall.name = @"hisWall";
EnemyWall.position = CGPointMake(512, 260);
EnemyWall.xScale = 0.09;
EnemyWall.yScale = 0.09;
EnemyWall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategoryEnemyWall;
EnemyWall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategoryEnemy;
EnemyWall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
[self addChild:EnemyWall];
```

}

// For the enemy character I have this code

```
- (void) Enemy {
    _Enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
    _Enemy.position = CGPointMake(520, _Enemy.size.height/1.50);
    _Enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width];
    _Enemy.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    _Enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategoryEnemy;
    _Enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategoryEnemyWall;
    _Enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    [self addChild:_Enemy];
}
```

// For the enemy movement I have this code

```
- (void) EnemySpawner {
    [ForEnemy runAction:appear2 completion:^{
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
    [_Enemy runAction:wait];
    SKAction *actionXMove2 = [SKAction moveToX:ForEnemy.position.x duration:0.14];
    SKAction *actionYMove2 = [SKAction moveToY:ForEnemy.position.y duration:0.14];
    [_Enemy runAction:actionYMove2];
    [_Enemy runAction:actionXMove2];
}];
```

}

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategoryEnemy && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask 
    == PhysicsCategoryEnemyWall)
{
    SKNode *enemy = contact.bodyA.node;  // a is the enemy here
       // Code here
    SKNode *wall = contact.bodyB.node; // b is the enemy's wall here
       // Code here
}
else if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategoryEnemy && 
    contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategoryEnemyWall)
{
    SKNode *enemy = contact.bodyB.node;
       // Code here
    SKNode *wall = contact.bodyA.node;
       // Code here
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to `applyImpulse` on the node's physicsBody to make it simulate naturally and interact with other physicsBodies.

Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165339/2043580) on how to do the same.

Copy the rwAdd, rwSub, rwMult, rwLength and the rwNormalize methods from this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) by Ray Wenderlich.

Then, try using this code:

```
[ForEnemy runAction:appear2 completion:^{
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];

        CGPoint offset = rwSub(location, ForEnemy.position);
        CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);
        float forceValue = 200; //Edit this value to get the desired force.
        CGPoint shootAmount = rwMult(direction, forceValue);

        CGVector impulseVector = CGVectorMake(shootAmount.x, shootAmount.y);

        [_Enemy.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulseVector];


         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

PhysicsWorld should simulate bounces automatically. Just set your nodes' physics properties accordingly. Look for the 'restitution' property. It will determine the bounciness of your objects.

And don't use SKAction to move your enemies. This will just "teleport" your nodes around. They don't get to have any real velocity in the physicsWorld (and hence don't bounce). Instead, apply forces to your bodies (or set velocity vector manually).

Comment: well here is my problem with the SKAction. the items like health items on the map appears at random locations at random time and this enemy is just goes to those locations to pick them up. so what do you suggest if I want to keep having him picking up stuff and still avoid running into the wall for doing so? I see that you say apply forces. so is there a way to apply force to have my character pushed to the item's location on the map? Thanks budd.

Comment: I'm afraid it gets a bit more complicated than that. You can apply forces and impulses only to a one direction at a time. So you have to implement some sort of an AI for you enemy objects. Basically, in every iteration (e.g. in update-method), you calculate the direction where next collectible is located. Then you "push" your enemy a bit to that direction. If there is nothing in the way, your enemy should eventually get to the item. However, if your enemy collides to a wall, you have to make him smart enough to go around it.