# SKAction problems when reloading the game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm having some problems with a SKAction when clicking retry after the player dies. It's the shooting SKAction that I'm having difficulty with. It's shooting well when I run the game but when I click "Retry" to play again only one bullet fires. After that, the SKAction stops. All the other SKActions work when i play again, but not that one.

I know what the problem is. I have all the relevant functions in a func called initialize() that I add in the didMove. But I'm having difficulty calling some of the functions there since the functions have a parameter.

These are the shooting functions I have:

```
func fireMissile() {
    let missile = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 20, 
    height: 5))
    missile.name = "Missile"
    missile.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 28, y: 
    player.position.y + 10)
    missile.zPosition = 2
    missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: missile.size)
    missile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Bullet
    missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy | 
    ColliderType.Boat
    missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy | 
    ColliderType.Boat

    let missileFlightTime = travelTime(to: missileDestination, from: 
    player.position, atSpeed: missileSpeed)
    missile.zRotation = direction(to: missileDestination, from: 
    missile.position)

    self.addChild(missile)

    let missileMove = SKAction.move(to: missileDestination,
                                    duration: 
    TimeInterval(missileFlightTime))
    let missileRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    missile.run(SKAction.sequence([missileMove, missileRemove]))
}

func travelTime(to target : CGPoint, from : CGPoint, atSpeed speed : 
    CGFloat) -> TimeInterval {
    let distance = sqrt(pow(abs(target.x - from.x),2) +
        pow(abs(target.y - from.y),2))
    return TimeInterval(distance/speed)
}


func direction(to target : CGPoint, from: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let x = target.x - from.x
    let y = target.y - from.y
    var angle = atan(y / x)
    if x < 0 {
        angle = angle + CGFloat.pi
    }
    return angle
}
```

And then we have the didMove function:

```
func initialize() {

    score = 0

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    createPlayer()
    createBG()
    createWall()
    spawnEnemiesLeft()
    spawnEnemiesRight()
    spawnBoat()
    fireMissile()

    createlabel()
}
```

When i try adding the "func travelTime()" and func "direction()", it requires for me to also add the CGPoint for the "to target" and "from", and I don't know what to type in there, I don't know if thats even the way to go, but it should be.

Comment: It seems to me that SKActions are precise mouvements and heavy functions. Projectiles should be more random and light. It would be better to use the SKPhysicsbodies in a physic context and use ApplyImpulse toward a given point, the target. This link should help you to acheive this and be a way around to your problem :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157138/applyimpulse-towards-cgpoint-spritekit

Comment: You create functions but have no idea how they work? How is this even possible?

Comment: Your attitude is really poor a lot of times. Did you just search for my questions to find something to complain about? Just ignore me, please.